# how to display data from multiple tables to dataGridView

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

I want to display the phonebook and email data in one dataGridView. and the problem is it will only display the email table

```
MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConnectionString);
connection.Open();
try
{
    MySqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM phonebook";
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM email";
    MySqlDataAdapter adap = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    adap.Fill(ds);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
finally
{
    if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        connection.Clone();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to `JOIN` your tables? Because like that, your `cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM phonebook";` line is useless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to join two tables and fetch the results as below

```
using(MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConnectionString))
using(MySqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    connection.Open();
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT pb.Id, pb.Name, pb.MobileNo, e.email FROM phonebook pb INNER JOIN email e ON e.Id= pb.Id";
    MySqlDataAdapter adap = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    adap.Fill(ds);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
}
```